# Loop through a table and copy non blank rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table "Table1" that contains all the orders we have in-process. I would like to loop through this table to find rows that have a completion time entered, and move those to the completed table on another sheet. So it needs to loop through the table, check to see if the completion time column is empty. This is column 8 in the table and column J in the workbook.

I have tried a few recommendations found on Stack and other sites, but nothing seems to be working. The following code does not return an error, but does nothing.

```vb
Sub closeItems()
    Dim i, iLastRow As Integer
    Dim oLastRow As ListRow

    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count

    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If Cells(i, 8).Value <> vbNullString Then
            Rows(i).Copy
            Set oLastRow = Worksheets("Finished").ListObject("Finished").ListRows.Add
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I would like to move the entries that are completed to the completed table and delete the row from the active table.

Comment: Using a filter for this would be much more efficient than looping through rows.

Comment: I would start by putting a `Debug.Print(iLastRow)` prior to entering the loop, just to make sure that the `Count` statement is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that filters, copies and deletes

```
Sub closeItems()

Dim tb1 As ListObject
Dim tb2 As ListObject
Dim Lrow As Long

Set tb1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set tb2 = Worksheets("Finished").ListObjects("Finished")
Lrow = tb2.ListRows.Count

tb1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
NumRows = tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
tb2.DataBodyRange(Lrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darrell. I had to edit the code a little, but was able to get this approach to work. Great idea, and much better than looping.